# How can I choose the type of view in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I can create my view in Django with :

- Function Base View
- Class Base View
- Generic Views & Mixins
- ViewSets

Now is there any standard to tell us when should we use which?

and why we have this much type at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard but you can start with this simple strategy:

1. Specific action on a model class -- [generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) (`RetrieveAPIView`,
   `ListAPIView`, `UpdateAPIView`, etc.)
2. Several actions in one class and basic CRUD -- [ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets) ([`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) and [`ReadOnlyModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#readonlymodelviewset) are most useful)
3. Some action on 1 instance -- ViewSet + [`@action(detail=True)`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)
4. Some action on several or all objects -- ViewSet +[`@action(detail=False)`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)
5. Simplest custom actions -- [function based views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views) or `@action` again.

Also check [DRF views classes](http://www.cdrf.co/) for quick overview.